# Nextcloud no access to occ UPDATE: Trying to change a password in LDAP conf

Tags: nextcloud

I’m in big need for help. So I had my Nextcloud server up and running. After I went to do some LDAP changes why server started crashing. I know how to fix it but it’s not working.

Basically there’s an error in my LDAP config file.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgvuq.png)
**sudo -u nextcloud php7.4 /var/www/nextcloud/occ ldap:show-config**
When I try to do that I get told that “Could not open input file”.

I already did **sudo chmod 744 /var/www/nextcloud/** and **sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/nextcloud/**

Not sure what I should do now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually got this to work by giving chwon to user nextcloud.

Comment: Now I'm trying to change the password when I was setting up LDAP. Using this "sudo -u nextcloud php occ ldap:set-config "What do I type here now". The password field is "ldapAgentPassword".